# Array of Superclass Instances

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a homework which I am trying to complete, but so far I am not able to find solution, my problem is this:

I have a Superclass Person which is extended by classes Student and Employee.
Person has fields name,age,male, then Student has score and Employee has salary.
For all of the classes I have method to print info for the objects.
Example for Person:

void showPersonInfo() {

```
    System.out.println( this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " name: " + this.name);
    System.out.println(  this.getClass().getSimpleName() +" age : " + this.age);
    System.out.println(isMale ?  this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is male" : this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is female");
}
```

and for Employee(its the same for Student):

```
void showEmployeeInfo(){
    super.showPersonInfo();
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " salary per day is: " + this.daySalary);
}
```

Then I have a main method in which I have to make an array of 10 Persons and to fill it with Students,Persons and Employees.
After iteration I have to call accordingly the methods for the subclass - showEmployeeInfo for Employee, etc. I think you got the idea.

So far I've done this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < guys.length; index++) {
            if(guys[index].getClass() == Person.class) {
                guys[index].showPersonInfo();
                System.out.println();
            }
```

I am trying to do the same for the other classes, and I manage to find them with getClass() but I cant call the subclass methods. Is this even possible? I tried some things so far but nothing worked.. Any ideas?

P.S: I think I can make all of the methods static, but I don't think this should be the solution. :)

Comment: What is `guys` defined as? If it's a `Person[]`, then you can do something like `if (guys[index] instanceof Employee) { ((Employee)guys[index]).showEmployeeInfo(); }`

Comment: That worked just fine! Thank you very much, so far we havent learned the use of "instanceof" but this is a good time to start! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is not necessarily the answer that your teacher/instructor expects.

---

You can change the name of the `showXXXInfo` methods to just `showInfo`, and have the methods in the subclasses override the one in the superclass:

```
// in Person
void showInfo() {

    System.out.println( this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " name: " + this.name);
    System.out.println(  this.getClass().getSimpleName() +" age : " + this.age);
    System.out.println(isMale ?  this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is male" : this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is female");

}

// in Employee
@Override
void showInfo(){
    super.showInfo();
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " salary per day is: " + this.daySalary);
}
```

Now you can just call `showInfo` on each element of your array and depending on the type, the correct method will be automatically called.

Comment: That came to my mind... If there is no other solution I will probably do it, but as your disclaimer says I believe this is not the answer, cuz in the task it is said that methods should have those names... :) Thanks tho! :)

Comment: @IvanMichev note that this is the solution your teacher _should_ be aiming to teach you, rather than the `instanceof` cascade.